# How to make the style of a div grow with the div's size?

Tags: html, css, styles, stylesheet

I have a div in a HTML file that contains all the search results from a query, so its size is dynamic. I gave it the following style written in CSS:

```
#content {
position: absolute;
width: 75%;
min-height: 100%;
left: 13%;
right: 12%;
top: 12%;
background-color: #FFF;
border-left: 3px solid #81DAF5;
border-bottom: 3px solid #81DAF5;
word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Everything works just fine if there are not many search results, i. . e. if they all fit onto the screen, but as soon as there are so many results that the user must scroll to see them all, the div grows (the elements in the overflow follow the position instructions from the CSS code), but its white color and the borders don't. This looks very silly and I have not found a way to solve this issue. Can anyone please help me?

Edit: I forgot to mention that if I do the same thing manually with paragraphs of text in the HTML file, everything works as expected, i. e. the div expands with every style I gave it.

Answer (score 1):

Kirk's answer will allow you to scroll but you may want to add a parent element with relative position. That way, when you set the height of the absolutely positioned element to 100% it will take up 100% of the height of parent element. The relatively positioned parent element should expand cleanly with the data.

So you may want to style the parent element in this case.

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="dynamic-content"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent {
   position: relative;
   background-color: #FFF;
   border-left: 3px solid #81DAF5;
   border-bottom: 3px solid #81DAF5;
   margin: 12% auto 0;
}

.dynamic-content {
  height: 100%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: I tried it out, but it didn't work out well, there seems to be more going on in my code that is not quite compatible with this. However, I know that this should work. Never mind, I've just figured out another way of doing it, but nevertheless thank you for your help and your time.

Answer (score 0):

You could add:

```
overflow-y: scroll;
```

At that point, the box remains the same size, but it becomes scrollable to see however many results there may be.

Edit --

Alternatively, you could try:

```
min-height: 100%;
```

To allow it to expand beyond it's initial size.

Comment: Yeah, I know, but that is not what I want, I want the page to be scrollable, but only by the scroll bar that is already there in the browser.

Comment: Have you looked at min-height: 100%? That would set the height to 100%, but then allow it to expand depending on the content.

Comment: Oh damn, I actually work with min-height, I've typed it in wrong above. But even with that this strange behavior remains unsless I fill the page manually with paragraphs. In this latter case, strange enough, it behaves as expected.

Comment: Sounds like there might be more going on here, then. Maybe you could post more of your html or a link to a demonstration?

Comment: It's all right, I've just figured out another way of doing it, but anyway, thanks für your help and time.